# How to deal with empty rows when its value can be in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe where it has two columns to represent a user's location (city and address)

The data looks like this:

```
        City        Address

0     New York     Lincoln Square 
1      Null         Chicago
2      Null         Los Angeles, Beverly Hills
3      Utah          Null
```

Using Pandas, I'm trying to delete the null in column City, but the City name itself is given in the Address column.

How can I approach this?

The desired outcome

```
        City           Address

0      New York      Lincoln Square
1       Chicago         Chicago
2     Los Angeles    Los Angeles, Beverly Hills
3        Utah         Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by splitted `Address` by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and selecting first lists:

```
#if necessary
#df['City'] = df['City'].replace('Null',np.nan)

df['City'] = df['City'].fillna(df['Address'].str.split(',').str[0])
```